What is the relationship between the US trade deficit and the USD dominating the world's trade?
Per Bloomberg:

The president-elect's warning against the BRICS nations suggests "how confused the incoming administration is about the global trade and capital system," according to Michael Pettis, a senior fellow at the Carnegie Endowment for International Peace.
"The US cannot both reduce its trade deficit and increase the global dominance of USD because these impose diametrically opposed conditions," Pettis said on his X account.

What is the relationship between the trade deficit and the global dominance of the USD, such that one can't reduce the former while increasing the latter? The source is silent on this, and Pettis doesn't appear to say either on his X account (or I'm not using X correctly).
